# Event is fire, if I add class

Tags: jquery, events, mouseenter

If I add class ...

```
$(".cart").addClass("show_cart");
```

... it fire mouseenter and than mouseleave event

```
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            ....
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            ....
        }
    }, '.show_cart');
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is event fired? I would like to fire event mouseenter only if I move mouse over element.

Comment: Adding a class does not trigger any events. If you're getting this behaviour then it's being caused by some other logic. Can you add a working example to the question which included all relevant code

Comment: Here's a fiddle you can use to see what's going on:  https://jsfiddle.net/hugeacpx/  you'll see that adding the class doesn't fire the event (given the code you've provided) even when the mouse is already inside when the class is added.

Comment: I *guess* it could depend on what `.show_cart` actually does - eg if it there's some css animation - it might be that when it's displayed it appears where the mouse is (eg if there's an "open cart" button) or maybe slides-in from the side going under the mouse as it does so.  As in the comment above, please providing a working snippet that *demonstrates* the problem.  Have a read of [mcve].